# Python os.getcwd() always returns cygwin formatted path

Tags: python, cygwin

I've been placed in charge of a build server at work, and I can't for the life of me figure out why os.getcwd() always returns a cygdrive directory.  Any clue how to get it back to returning a non-cygdrive path all the time?

Comment: It depends on what directory the application was launched from. Do an os.chdir("<your desired directory>") and then try again

Comment: So I've tried running this command from a jenkins job, and from command prompt in multiple locations and I always seem to have the same result.  I have a theory I'm chasing down right now that the person before me installed python in the cygdrive, somehow.

Comment: yup.  the issue was that the path environment variable had the cygwin directory before the python directory, which meant that anytime you tried to run python, it would run the python 2.6 package installed as part of cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered the issue.  For some reason there were 3 python installations.  The default was supposed to be set to 2.7.2, but for some reason kept running 2.6.5
Python 2.7.2 worked fine when called manually, so I uninstalled 2.6.5.

It also seems, upon further research, that this could also have been solved by remounting the drive (info here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44677/how-do-i-get-rid-of-cygwins-cygdrive-prefix-in-all-paths )